# How can I overlay text on a TIFF image, creating something like a searchable pdf?

Tags: pdf, ocr, tiff

I would like to have an application where a user views an image of a document in TIFF Format.

If the words "foo" and "bar" appear on the page. And a selection is made on the image that only contains "foo", then I would like to only select the word "foo".

Is there a format that lends itself to storing both the location of text and the text of an image?

Comment: What's wrong with PDF? You can do exaclty that in PDF. Any PDF file with OCR applied to it will be like this.

Comment: I need to build a database of documents.

Comment: Is https://stackoverflow.com/a/73800066/9731176 of use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you know about searchable PDF, and it perfectly implements what you are suggesting, I assume that there is some reason why you can't use it.  If not, you should use PDF -- the format supports mixed-content and overlaying them.  All of the viewers that your users are likely to have will understand what to do with text beneath the image.

The TIFF format does not support this directly, but if you are making the viewer, and it only needs to work there, then you could try to store the text and positions in a custom tag.

Then your viewer would need to read this tag, interpret mouse positions, and look up the text that is being selected on the image.  No other viewer would support your text tag, but they would show the TIFF.

For either of these mechanisms, you will need OCR and a way to encode the data you get either into PDF or the custom TIFF tag.  For open source OCR, take a look at Tesseract from Google.

Disclaimer: I work at Atalasoft.  Our imaging SDK, [DotImage](http://atalasoft.com/products/dotimage), has add-ons for OCR that can make searchable PDF, and can add and edit TIFF tags.

Comment: However, would an OCR PDF still contain the original TIFF (with its metadata) or would it need to convert the embedded image to another format?

Comment: It contains the image data of the TIFF, not an embedded TIFF File. You would need to translate the meta data to PDF meta data.

Comment: Don't PDFs use an embedded but separate image format like JPEG rather than represent the image data in a custom format? Surely is must be converted to another image format before embedding unless it directly embeds the TIFF data?

Comment: My understanding is that it uses the same image format for the pixels, but I don’t think that it’s literally an embedded JPEG file, which also contains metadata. I’m not 100% sure