# Is there a standard way to add textual information in a TIFF file with FreeImage?

Tags: tiff

I have a program that generates its results as TIFF files. I would like to add some textual information in theses files to keep a trace of the program parameters.

I know that a tag named "ImageDescription" can be added in a tiff file (according to the [specification file](http://exif.org/TIFF6.pdf) p34), if I could put the program parameters in that field, it will be ok for me.

But is it possible to set this tag with [FreeImage](http://freeimage.sourceforge.net/)?

If it's not possible, can I add EXIF information to my tiff file with FreeImage?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I answer my own question.

With FreeImage, one simple way to add metadata is to use `IPTC` tags:

```
void addTag(FIBITMAP *bitmap, const char *key, const char *value)
{
    FITAG *tag = FreeImage_CreateTag();
    size_t len = strlen(value)+1;
    FreeImage_SetTagKey(tag, len);
    FreeImage_SetTagCount(tag, len);
    FreeImage_SetTagType(tag, FIDT_ASCII);
    FreeImage_SetTagValue(tag, value);
    FreeImage_SetMetadata(FIMD_IPTC, bitmap, FreeImage_GetTagKey(tag), tag);
    FreeImage_DeleteTag(tag);
}
```

And, use these function with valid [`IPTC` tags](http://www.iptc.org/std/IIM/4.1/specification/IIMV4.1.pdf):

```
// set creator's name, limited to 32 bytes
addTag(bitmap, "By-line", "Creator's name");
// set keyword, limited to 64 bytes
addTag(bitmap, "Keywords", "Param1=foo;Param2=bar");
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73800066/9731176 states that this shall not work.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to modify Mathieve's answer little bit. Otherwise it will not work.

```
void addTag(FIBITMAP *bitmap, const char *key, const char *value)
{
    FITAG *tag = FreeImage_CreateTag();
    if(tag)
    {
       size_t len = strlen(value)+1;
       FreeImage_SetTagKey(tag, len);
       //Tag length, tag count and tag type should be set before setting tag value
       FreeImage_SetTagLength(tag, len);
       FreeImage_SetTagCount(tag, len);
       FreeImage_SetTagType(tag, FIDT_ASCII);
       FreeImage_SetTagValue(tag, value);
       FreeImage_SetMetadata(FIMD_IPTC, bitmap, FreeImage_GetTagKey(tag), tag);
       //Delete tag after setting the metadata
       FreeImage_DeleteTag(tag);
    }
}
```

And, use these function with valid IPTC tags in [FreeImage documentation](https://file:///C:/Users/priyani.jayamanna/Downloads/FreeImage3180.pdf):

```
// set creator's name, limited to 32 bytes
addTag(bitmap, "By-line", "Creator's name");
// set keyword, limited to 64 bytes
addTag(bitmap, "Keywords", "Param1=foo;Param2=bar");
```